# Possible issues with displaying integers

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on an assignment using C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 in Microsoft Visual Studios. I'm attempting to make an Income Tax Calculator.
This is what I have so far :

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*This method will take user input and
         * Calculate the income tax owed
        */

        
        double TI = double.Parse(txtTaxableIncome.Text);
        double rate;
        double owed = 0;

        if (TI <= 9225)
        {
            rate = 0.10;
        }
        else if (TI <= 37450)
        {
            rate = 0.15;
        }
        
        else
        {
            rate = 0.396;
        }

        owed = TI * rate;

        Console.WriteLine(owed);



    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This method closes the form when called upon

        this.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Anytime I run it and put in a number nothing gets displayed in the "Income Tax Owed" field.
Also this is my first time using this site, so if there is a better way I should approach or an etiquette I didn't follow, I apologize.

Comment: You are writing the output to the Console.  You need something like `txtIncomeTaxOwed.Text = owed.ToString();`, instead of `Console.WriteLine(owed):`

Comment: `txtIncomeTaxOwed.Text = $"{owed:c2}";` or alike

Comment: Your code has no integers (other than `0` that gets implicitly cast to `double` when you assign it to `owed`).

Comment: You should also note that when doing financial calculations, decimal is the preferred datatype over double & float. See, for example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709941/double-or-decimal-for-amount.html